# Doctrine onDelete relation SET NULL and set other field

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

How to also set `$isSuspended` to `true` when Teacher is removed ?

```php
<?php
class Teacher {

    /**
     *@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Activities", mappedBy="teacher")
     */
    protected $activities;
}

class Activities {
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Teacher", inversedBy="activities")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="teacher_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    protected $teacher;

    /**
     * Activities are suspended when there is not teacher 
     */
    protected $isSuspended = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part `onDelete="SET NULL"` works on a database level, so for changing the `$isSuspended` field, you can create a listener for the `postRemove` doctrine event.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

public function postRemove(LifecycleEventArgs $event)
{
    $entity = $event->getEntity();
    if ($entity instanceof Teacher) {
        foreach($entity->getActivities() as $activity) {
            $activity->setIsSuspended(true);

            $event->getEntityManager()->persist($activity);
        }

        $event->getEntityManager()->flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping there is a more natural way to do that. By the way if you were to suppose to use DDD how would you implement this if you would want to keep all of the business logic in one place?

Comment: With DDD we can use domain events(https://romaricdrigon.github.io/2019/08/09/domain-events), this will still use doctrine events, but we will not be so tied to the doctrine.